# In Thurston's notes on hyperbolic geometry, why does a geodesic always belong to a 2D subspace?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

On page 12 of [1] (in the subsection titled *Trigonometry*), Thurston derives the equation of a geodesic in the hyperboloid model of hyperbolic geometry. The hyperboloid in the hyperboloid model is given by $x^2 + y^2 - t^2 = 1$. The metric tensor is given by $g_{ij}=\begin{cases}1, & i = j < 3 \\ -1, & i = j = 3 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$. **At some point, he states that "any geodesic must lie in a two-dimensional subspace"**, and from that claim he derives that $\ddot{X}_t = -(s/r)^2X_t$ (where we can set $r = s = 1$ without any loss of generality, because they are constants). Thurston appears to be using a general fact about geodesics in Riemannian manifolds to conclude that a geodesic in the hyperboloid model of hyperbolic geometry is always the intersection of the hyperboloid with a plane that passes through the origin. What general fact is he using? By what fact in Riemannian geometry must a geodesic lie on a 2-dimensional vector subspace?

[1] - http://library.msri.org/books/gt3m/PDF/2.pdf

Comment: The question about hyperbolic geodesics was asked on this site many times. There are several ways to identify them, one of which is to use the geodesic equation $\frac{D}{dt}\gamma'(t)=0$ and the fact that the connection on the hyperbolic space is induced from the flat Lorentzian connection. Another is to use symmetries and the fact that fixed-point sets of isometries are totally geodesic.

Comment: @MoisheKohan The question is more about "any geodesic must lie a in a two-dimensional subspace", which is about more than hyperbolic geometry

Comment: I'll check it out.

Comment: In the context of general Riemannian metrics, there is no natural notion of 2-dimensional subspaces.

Comment: By a 2d subspace, I assume that Thurston means a totally geodesic submanifold, which is itself a hyperbolic $2$-manifold. I think it's easiest using any of the geometric models and the transitivity of isometries. Using the Poincaré model, you observe that you can map the geodesic to a line segment through the origin and any disk containing that geodesic is a $2$-dimensional subspace. Similar arguments can be used for the half-space and hyperboloid models.

Comment: In n both the Poincare and half-space models, a geodesic is a half-circle or line segment, which lies in a 2d linear subpsace of the ambient space. The intersection of this plane with the ball or half-space is a 2d hyperbolic subspace.

Comment: I have to add that you can show very easily that these intersections are totally geodesic subspaces isometric to the hyperbolic plane using only the synthetic geometric properties of hyperbolic space. No calculations are needed at all. I think for that reason Thurston considered the fact obvious.